# Уточнение брать в запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

> Юная гимнастка заняла второе место на Всероссийских соревнованиях в
> Санкт-Петербурге!
> А в Москве(,) во дворце Ирины Винер-Усмановой(,) её команда заняла 14 место
> среди 40 сильнейших сборных России.

1. Нужны ли запятые?
2. Лучше написать 14-е и 40-е вместо 14 и 40?

Comment: вырвано из контекста. дополните, пожалуйста, предложение, чтобы было на что опираться.

Comment: Дополнила ещё одним предложением (см. вопрос).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Запятые факультативны, зависят от того, рассматривает ли автор *во дворце Ирины Винер-Усмановой* как уточняющее обстоятельство или нет.
   Розенталь:

> В зависимости от смысла одни и те же слова могут рассматриваться или
> не рассматриваться как уточняющее обстоятельство. Ср.:
> *Впереди на дороге толпились люди* (т. е. в передней части дороги). —
> *Впереди, на дороге, толпились люди* (т. е. сама дорога находилась
> впереди);
> *Далеко в лесу раздавались удары топора* (слушатель находится в лесу). —
> *Далеко, в лесу, раздавались удары топора* (слушатель находится вне
> леса);
> *Дети расположились на поляне между кустами* (поляна окружена кустами, а
> на самой поляне их нет). — *Дети расположились на поляне, между кустами*
> (кусты находятся на самой поляне).

2. Либо **её команда заняла 14-е место среди 40 сильнейших сборных России**, либо прописью: **её команда заняла четырнадцатое место среди сорока сильнейших сборных России**.

Comment: Спасибо. Ответ приняла, а вот зарегистрироваться не получается через почту. Ошибка высвечивается. Поэтому на галочку нажать не могу.

Comment: @Nektoid  А мне это объяснение Розенталя не нравится, однажды мы уже обсуждали эти поляны и кусты. Ну кто в художественном тексте будет определять  расположение  кустов по знакам препинания!

Comment: @Sharon зачем "определять"? Это само воспринимается. Грамотными людьми, по крайней мере.

Comment: @Nektoid Если сюжет захватывающий, то там не до запятых даже грамотным людям. :) А если серьезно, то пространство, где происходят события, изображается как-то по-другому,  а не с помощью запятых. Ну, я так думаю.

Comment: @Sharon зачем избегать удобного и не требующего лишних слов метода? Неужели не воспринимается на лету разница между *Дети расположились // на поляне между кустами* и *Дети расположились на поляне, // между кустами*?

Comment: А вы бы, Sharon, поставили здесь запятые (предложение в моём вопросе)? Автор не поставил. Я бы - да! Здесь пауза напрашивается (А в Москве... ПАУЗА). Может, не права я.

Comment: Я бы обособила оборот, так как такое распространенное предложение сложно прочитать как предложение простое, то есть без обособления, Какую-то его часть нужно перенести на второй план речи. Естественно, что обособить нужно второе обстоятельство.  Поэтому вам и слышится эта пауза.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: С другой стороны, если автор не поставил запятые, то считать оформление неверным тоже нельзя. КАк это можно объяснить? Обособление оборота придает ему уточняющее значение и выделяет оборот, а автор, возможно, не захотел его выделять.  Но в любом случае наличие факультативности можно считать погрешностью письма. Все-таки желательно строить текст с большей определенностью. А вот обособление придает ему эту определенность, кажется естественным.

Comment: Согласна с Вами!

Comment: @Nektoid Я немного не о том. Ведь по контексту мы примерно  представляем обстановку, где происходят события,   Если кусты обособляются, то мы уже в курсе, что они там есть. Если не обособляются, то зачем указывать на кусты? Может, там жарко, и дети хотели выбрать тенистое место. Это тоже все заранее понятно читателю, поэтому подобные рассуждения в правилах  делают эти правила абстрактными и придают им особую значимость,, не связанную со смыслом всего текста. Да еще приучают пользователей к формализму, не свойственному русской пунктуации.